# node.js and npm v3: How to add Travis tests compatible peerDependencies in package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

With *peerDependencies* in package.json I can make sure that the user has a specific module in the application rootfolder:

**module_a**

```
var modB = require('module_b')
...
```

**package.json of module_a**

```
...
"peerDependencies": {
  "module_b": "^1.0.1"
},
"dependencies": {
},
...
```

**my_app**

```
var modA = require('module_a')
var modB = require('module_b')
...
```

**file structure**

With npm v1/v2 this configuration works perfect: `npm install module_a` installs *module_a* and *module_b* in the rootfolder:

```
my_app
  node_modules
    module_a
    module_b
```

Great, that is what I want!

**npm v3**

But while installing with `npm install module_a`, npm v2 prints this warning:

```
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency module_b@^1.0.1 included
from module_a will no longer be automatically installed to fulfill the
peerDependency in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it
explicitly.
```

So, npm v3 will not install the peer dependency automatically, I have to install it manually for *my_app* to achieve the same result.

**The problem**

But what about in my tests when using npm v3?

npm v3 doesn't install the peer dependency, so travis will fail because it cannot find *module_b*. But I cannot add the module as regular dependency because than *my_app* and *module_a* use different "instances" of *module_b*:

```
my_app
  node_modules
    module_a
      node_modules
        module_b         // used by module_a
    module_b             // used by my_app
```

That is not what I want because *module_a* changes some parameters in *module_b*, but this changes aren't visible in *my_app*.

**Question**

How can I add *module_b* as (peer) dependency in the rootfolder without breaking the travis tests from *module_a*?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

If a module is not in the dependencies list but is required to run the tests, then you should list it as a devDependency (regardless of whether it's also a peerDependency).

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by installing the peer dependencies in travis' *before_install* hook.
My *.travis.yml* looks like so:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "6.1"
  - "5.11"
  - "4.4"
before_install:
  - "npm install peerDependency"
```